# Django - Where to put CSV reading code

Tags: python, django

I have an app and I'm working on writing code to let me take a csv file and put it into my database but I can't figure out where to put that code. I'm planning on just using the console to run the .py file that the code is in but I need it to be able to use the Django get_or_create function.

How do I go about doing this?  I'm new to Python and Django so I'm good and lost.

Comment: Read about custom management commands https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/. You will be able to run them from a terminal (with something like `python manage.py import_csv`) and also have access to anything in your apps or Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Adrian Ghiuta, doing it through custom management commands would be the way to do this if you need to make this repeatable.

A second option would be to convert the csv file into json objects that map to your data model and then just do `python manage.py loaddata example_from_csv.json`.

However, the simplest way to get started would be to write a one-off python script in your app directory.  You can then do python manage.py shell to bring up a django aware shell and just do import one-off (assuming your script is called one-off.py).  Within one-off.py, you can e.g. do something like

```
import csv
from .models import MyModel

... # get the data out of the csv file using the python csv library

for data in csvdata:
   MyModel.objects.get_or_create(data[0])
```